# Multithreading so that numbers are constantly being subtracted or added from a set int

Tags: java

I want to have 3 threads executing at the same time one for adding to Total, one subtracting from total and one to check the total. The amount subtracted  or added is inputed by the user via console.

So far I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc implements Runnable {

public int add;
public int remove;
public static int Total;

static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int add(int a){
    System.out.println("How much was added? \n");
    a = s.nextInt();
    Total = Total + a;
    return Total;
}


public int remove(int b){
    System.out.println("How much was removed? \n");
    b = s.nextInt();
    return Total = Total - b;
}

public void check(){
    System.out.println("Would you like to know how much is left? \n");
    if(s.nextLine().equals("Yes"))
        System.out.println(Total);

}


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}


public class Calculate{
public static void main(String[] args){

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Calc("add"));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Calc("remove"));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Calc("check"));

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}
}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this is useful in any way but for your particular needs you could "probably" get away with something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) { // change condition to whatever
                    add();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) { // change condition to whatever
                    remove();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) { // change condition to whatever
                    check();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }

    static int total = 0;

    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    static synchronized int add() {
        System.out.println("How much was added?");
        int a = s.nextInt();
        total = total + a;
        return total;
    }

    static synchronized int remove() {
        System.out.println("How much was removed?");
        int b = s.nextInt();
        return total = total - b;
    }

    static synchronized void check() {
        System.out.println("Would you like to know how much is left?");
        String str = s.next();
        if (str.equals("Yes"))
            System.out.println(total);

    }

}
```

note that you don't need to use threads for what you are trying to do.